# Adding new properties to JSON with a forloop doesn't work

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, for-loop

I'm trying to add new properties to an Array of JSON object dynamically using a for loop, but it's very weird that if I hardcode the index of the object instead of using i, it works.

This works:

```
sa.savannahWS.completedWorkOrder("09/29/2017").then(function(response) {                                    
                response.invocationResult.result[0].CSXPMTWO = "TEST";
                response.invocationResult.result[1].CSXPMTWO = "TEST";
                console.log(response.invocationResult.result);
                },  function(error) {
                    sa.savannahUtils.showErrorPopup("Error In Creating Wiring House", error);
                });
```

These doesn't work:

```
sa.savannahWS.completedWorkOrder("09/29/2017").then(function(response) {                    
                console.log(response.invocationResult.result);  
                for(var i = 0; i<response.invocationResult.result.size; i++) {
                        response.invocationResult.result[i].CSXPMTWO = "TEST";
                    }
                console.log(response.invocationResult.result);
                },  function(error) {
                    sa.savannahUtils.showErrorPopup("Error In Creating Wiring House", error);
                });
```

---

```
sa.savannahWS.completedWorkOrder("09/29/2017").then(function(response) {                    
                console.log(response.invocationResult.result);  
                for(var i = 0; i<response.invocationResult.result.size; i++) {
                        response.invocationResult.result[i]["CSXPMTWO"] = "TEST";
                    }
                console.log(response.invocationResult.result);
                },  function(error) {
                    sa.savannahUtils.showErrorPopup("Error In Creating Wiring House", error);
                });
```

---

```
sa.savannahWS.completedWorkOrder("09/29/2017").then(function(response) {                    
                console.log(response.invocationResult.result);  
                for(var i = 0; i<response.invocationResult.result.size; i++) {
                        response.invocationResult.result[i].push({"CSXPMTWO": "TEST"});
                    }
                console.log(response.invocationResult.result);
                },  function(error) {
                    sa.savannahUtils.showErrorPopup("Error In Creating Wiring House", error);
                });
```

Comment: if `response.invocationResult.result` is an array, then it should end in `.result.length`, not `.result.size`.

Comment: You are right. I made a silly mistake. ".length" worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure response.invocationResult.result.size is defined?  Usually for arrays, the size of the array is .length

Comment: You are 100% right. length worked. I dont' know why .size didn't give me an error in the console